# Pdf file is not downloading with content

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, struts2, pdfbox

I am trying to download a PDF file with Struts2. For generating the PDF I am using PDFBox.

I am able to download the PDF file, but the problem is that its size is 0 bytes.

Action Class

```java
public class BarcodeAction extends ActionSupport {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    //getter and setter

    public String getPdf() {
        System.out.println("Get Pdf");
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);
            PDFont headingFont = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = 
                            new PDPageContentStream(document, page, false, true);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(headingFont, 26);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(250, 700);
            contentStream.drawString("Hello World !");
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            document.save(bos);
            setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```xml
<action name="GenerateBarCode" class="foo.bar.BarcodeAction" method="getPdf">
   <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=test.pdf</param>
        <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
    <result name="input">/pages/ExpNImp/Export.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

How to download the PDF file properly ?

Comment: First try this and check if it is downloading any pdf `public String getPdf() throws Exception {
     inputStream= new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\downloadfile.pdf"));
     return SUCCESS;
 }`

Comment: Try to flush contentStream using  contentStream.flush()

Comment: Action and result code are fine. Are you sure the file is not 0 bytes inside the action ? Can you print `bos.toByteArray().length` before quitting the method ?

Comment: Thanks for comments. and giving fruitful suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made only one change not it is working
I removed 
 `document.close();`
from above code .

Now it is working properly

Comment: That is weird, after all you serialized the document before closing the document. probably there is some uncaught `Throwable`?